# react, get updated state after dispatch in functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use selector (don't have to) to retrieve the `nextStep`

I dispatch someAction and this can change `nextStep` that I want to do, however the `nextStep` doesn't get updated with the following code.

```
const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const nextStep = useSelector(getNextStep)

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(someAction())      // this can change the nextStep
    dispatch(gotoStep(nextStep))   //  this nextStep is computed before someAction
  }

}


export const getNextStep = (state) => {
  let {step, stepList} = state.my_reduxer
  let index = stepList.indexOf(step) // someAction changes stepList
  let next_step = stepList[index + 1]

  return next_step
}
```

How do I get the updated `nextStep` for `gotoStep` action?

-- Edit

I can think of something like the following but not sure if this guarantees the correct behavior

```
const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const nextStep = useSelector(getNextStep);
  const [done, setDone] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(someAction()); // this can change the nextStep

    setDone(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (done) {
      dipatch(gotoStep(nextStep)); //  nextStep is hopefully updated?
    }
  }, [done]);
};
```

Comment: Maybe your someAction() function doesn't correctly change the state. Remember that state is immutable in react. Can you provide your someAction() function code?

Comment: I think the problem is `nextStep` is captured at the time of calling `handleSubmit`

Comment: adding some information, any update to the state inside a same function will be batched and will be executed at the end together

Answer (score 1):

> `someAction` might change `nextStep` or it might not change nextStep, and I want to advance to `nextStep` after done is updated and `nextStep` is possibly updated.

This code guarantee you advance next step only when `done` changes and you don't get a staled value.

```
const App = () => {
  const nextStep = useSelector(getNextStep);
  const stepRef = useRef(nextStep);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(someAction());
    setDone(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (done) {
      dispatch(gotoStep(stepRef.current));
    }
  }, [done]);

  useEffect(() => {
    stepRef.current = nextStep;
  }, [nextStep]);
};
```

Comment: how by `setDone(true);`  you can gurantee that `dispatch(someAction())` reduced?

Comment: nextStep might be changed or not changed

Comment: Don't see any problem, did you check? Do you have a practical example?

Comment: well it's gonna take some time to extract minimum example, what I'm worrying is that if done is updated first and nextStep is updated afterward (because done is local setState, nextStep is part of redux state) Don't I have to worry about that?

Comment: Let me edit the example so you will get extra defence

Comment: I guess I can set `done` in redux state as well, then I guess I don't have to worry about the separate updates hopefully..

Comment: Use a reference to compare with the last updated step so it will guarantee that the `useEffect` triggered by `nextStep`.

Comment: I want to go to nextStep whether it changed or not , current code only advance to next step if it changes

Comment: Thats what you said... "what I'm worrying is that if done is updated first and nextStep is updated afterward"

Comment: someAction might change nextStep or it might not change nextStep, and I want to advance to nextStep after done is updated and nextStep is possibly updated.

Current code doesn't advance to next step after done, if nextStep is not changed

Comment: Ok, I think you should have said it earlier (or I didn't understand)

Comment: Thats my final answer, hope it helps, any further help please make a producible example in codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

what suppose to trigger your effect is `nextStep` itself, because if you use `done` state it's still not guaranteed that object was reduced already

```
useEffect(() => dipatch(gotoStep(nextStep)), [nextStep]);
```

in case that at init render you don't want this effect to run then use like follow

```
const [ isInit, setIsInit ] = useState(true)
useEffect(() => isInit ? setIsInit(false) : dipatch(gotoStep(nextStep)), [nextStep]);
```

and now your `handleSubmit` function takes care only for dispatching

```
const handleSubmit = () => dispatch(someAction()); // this can change the nextStep
```

Comment: nextStep might or might not change, so depending on nextStep might not trigger the effect ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the discussion @Dennis Vash !

I wasn't sure if your solution would solve the problem I asked in the comment

Here's my solution, I still don't have definitive documented answer, but feel safer with it. (and it seems to work)

```
const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const nextStep = useSelector(getNextStep);
  const myStepDone = useSelector(getMyStep);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(someAction()); // this can change the nextStep
    dispatch(updateMyStepDone()); // let's use redux state for done
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myStepDone) {
      dipatch(gotoStep(nextStep)); //  I hope actions I submitted in handleSubmit updates state simulateneously
    }
  }, [myStepDone]);
};
```

Comment: You will get eslint warning here its is recommended to listen to the warnings

Comment: umm, I have eslint on, but never seen warning for the stale value, :(

Comment: So it doesn't configure well, if you put this example in a sandbox you will notice the warning